# postgresql - Format an interval as time with large number of hours

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, date, select

I have an interval that is calculated between events that can be days or hours between them.

Some rows show the desirable

```
00:15:38.687282
```

While other give me a worse-to-read

```
2 days 22:20:33.505085
```

How can I make the second example return the following?

```
70:22:33.505085
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution:

```
select extract(epoch from interval '2 days 22:20:33.505085')/3600 * interval '1h';
┌─────────────────┐
│    ?column?     │
╞═════════════════╡
│ 70:20:33.505085 │
└─────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a custom representation with `extract()`:

```
floor(extract(epoch from val) / 60 / 60)
|| ':' || extract(minute from val)
|| ':' || extract(second from val)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=85309b82f89b98abd1f736b53aa08490)**:

```
select 
    floor(extract(epoch from val) / 60 / 60)
    || ':' || extract(minute from val)
    || ':' || extract(second from val) display
from (values ('2 days 22:20:33.505085'::interval)) as t(val)
```

```
| display         |
| :-------------- |
| 70:20:33.505085 |
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution:

```
SELECT
   extract(days from '2 days 22:20:33.505085'::interval) * interval '24 hour' + '22:20:33.505085'::interval

 ?column?     
-----------------
 70:20:33.505085
```

If you want to get more involved then that, account for months, years and so on then you will probably need to build a function.